# Unity - Does a script's Awake() run before other scripts' Start()?

Tags: unity-game-engine

They say Awake() is called before Start(), but they don't mention if these functions have to belong to the same script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> They say Awake() is called before Start(), but they don't mention if
>   these functions have to belong to the same script.

All Awake() in **the scene** are called before any Start(). Doesn't matter the script to which they belong. Unless the GameObject the script is attach to is inactive during start up Awake, then it is not called until GameObject is made active. From https://docs.unity3d.com:

### First Scene Load

These functions get called when a **scene** starts (once for each object in the scene).

- **Awake**: This function is always called before any Start functions and
  also just after a prefab  is instantiated. (If a GameObject is
  inactive during start up Awake is not called until it is made
  active.)
- **OnEnable**: (only called if the Object is active): This function is
  called just after the object is enabled. This happens when a
  MonoBehaviour instance is created, such as when a level is loaded or
  a GameObject  with the script component is instantiated.
- **OnLevelWasLoaded**: This function is executed to inform the game that a
  new level has been loaded.

Note that for objects added to the scene, the Awake and OnEnable functions for all scripts will be called before Start, Update, etc are called for any of them. Naturally, this cannot be enforced when an object is instantiated during gameplay.

More about this [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

**As an aside**: You didn't ask about this, but in case for any reason you need some scripts to be executed before others, you can check this [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html) about how to set the script execution order (This is about the order of the scripts, no the order of the methods inside each script)

Comment: Thank both of you for the answers. And yes, I mean objects that pre-exist in the scene, not to compare newly instantiated objects with existing ones. Actually I try to avoid setting script execution order because I feel I may mess up things when many more scripts are added later.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `Awake` and `OnEnable` are called right after another. So other than what I thought at first `OnEnable` is not called after *all* `Awake` are done but together for one script so in `OnEnable` one cannot rely on other scripts `Awake` .

Answer (score 2):

My Experiment showed **all the Awake() in a scene are executed before all the Start().**

I created 10 scripts and respectively put them on 10 game objects.

[image]

Comment: It also shows that there is no order between Awake/Start calls.